# get index without counting siblings

Tags: jquery, click

I have the following html.
HTML:

```
<div id="abc">
 <h1>hello</h1>
 <div class="xyz">
    <input type="button">Click Me</button>
 </div>
 <h1>Hello 1</h1>
 <div class="xyz">
    <input type="button">Click Me</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(':button').on('click', function(){
   alert($(this).closest('.xyz').index());
});
```

How can i get the index for `xyz` without counting other siblings. I am getting 1 and 3 (I know why :) ) but I want 0 and 1.

eq: for first button click, i want 0 and for second it should be 1.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1tqp6tx1/

Much appreciated for any help

Comment: what if you try `$('.xyz').index($(this).closest('.xyz'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class name inside the `.index()` too.

Try this:

```
$(':button').on('click', function(){
       alert($(this).closest('.xyz').index('.xyz'));
});
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1tqp6tx1/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.xyz').index($(this).closest('.xyz');
```